# Get parent datacontext brush from inside a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls

I got the following:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">                        
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="{Binding Path=GridTextColor}"></TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The datacontext looks like this:

```
class{
 items = List with items (each row has a name property)
 GridTextColor = Brush
}
```

I bind the listview with all items. Each item contains a name and that name shows up nicely in the listview.

The problem is that i want all items inside the DataTemplate to have the Foreground set to the brush.
With the code above that is not possible since when i am inside the DataTemplate i bind to the items that are sent in.
Question, how can i bind to the "parent datacontext" to get the correct foreground color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`RelativeSource`** in your binding to get parent's DataContext.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
           Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.GridTextColor,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
```

Or Set **`x:Name`** on ListView and bind using **`ElementName`**:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView">
   ....
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                Foreground="{Binding DataContext.GridTextColor,
                                     ElementName=myListView}" />
   ....
</ListView>
```